# Need to Install Mesos to get Mesos Slave?

Tags: mesos

I'm trying to get this question solve,

To get mesos slave, is it we have to install Mesos and start mesos slave set up or?

And also I have problem with mesos master which I run a command

`./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=*** --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos`

end up it does not continue to run so i stop it running. End up I run the same above command and I get error shown

`Failed to initialize, bind: Address already in use [98]`

Which part did I do wrongly?

Answer (score 4):

You have to run mesos-master first and then you can connect mesos slave running on a different node to the master. You can refer to [getting started](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/) guide of mesos. only one slave can connect to the master on the same port. If you get bind address already in use, you can try running slave on another port by passing `--port=value` parameter. Replace value with port number.

to start mesos master on localhost:

```
./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

to start and connect slave to master

```
./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050
```

to start and connect another slave to the same master you have to use another port as default port 5051 is already used by the first connected slave. Use argument `--port-value` to start slave on another port

```
./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --port=5053
```

You may get a permission denied error. If so use sudo to access the given port

```
sudo ./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --port=5053
```

Comment: I would like to ask, example we have set up master and 1 slave and I want to create another slave, is it we have to do all the Mesos installation and mesos slave command to get it done or we can just run the mesos-slave without any other installation?

Comment: You dont want to go for another mesos installation. You can start slave on a different port. Refer to the answer given above. If this resolved your issue then you may mark it as the right answer that this post help others.

Answer (score 1):

You can run one more slave but you have to specify ip and a different workdir using

```
./mesos-slave.sh --master=<ipaddr>:<port> --ip=<ip of slave> --work_dir=<work_dir other than that of a running slave> --port=<another_port>
```

edit your etc/hosts and add more local ips with the following entries

```
127.0.0.2   slave2
127.0.0.3   slave3
```

then you can replace `--ip=<ip of slave>` with `--ip=slave1` or `--ip=slave2`

You may have to replace `<another_port>` with ports like 5052,5053 or any available port if you have a running slave. The slave will be using the default port.

Answer (score 0):

To run only a mesos-slave on a host is simple by installing the mesos package and only running the mesos-slave process with the correct flags, it's not a problem if the master is also installed, but be careful only to run the masters correct to the quorum number.

Something already running on the port you are trying to start the mesos-master, which has a web interface.
Check what program runs on the mesos default port, or use another port, more info about the command line documentation available here: [Mesos configuration](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/)

To see what's using port 5050 or 5051 use either one of these commands:

```
sudo fuser -v 5050/tcp
sudo lsof -i | grep 5050
```

Both command will give you the process pid which holds the port. Either kill them or specify a new port for mesos by starting it with the correct port option:

```
./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=*** --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --port=FREE_PORT
```

Where do you specify the zookeepers for the mesos master and slaves? The following flags are required to start mesos-master (see the link I gave you):
--advertise_ip, --advertise_port, --quorum, --work_dir, --zk

What are your current full configuration for mesos master? You can find the files under related at `/etc/mesos/`, `/etc/mesos-master/`, `/etc/mesos-slave/`, `/etc/defaults/mesos`, `/etc/defaults/mesos-master`, `/etc/defaults/mesos-slave`. If you copy paste the lines from them and the mesos log here, we might give you more help.

Also please explain the cluster you would like to set up (Number of hosts, masters, slaves) and we can also help there.

Answer (score 0):

excecute below command :
sudo netstat -peanut

Then check which process is using the port 5050 and 5051. 
Kill those process using the pid.

Start the mesos master and slave again.

This happens to me when I killed the mesos slave accidentally and then restarted it but failed with address-bind issue.